# How to Convert Seconds to Time Expressed in HH:MM:SS in timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I have a dataframe where I want to add the duration (in seconds) to the start-time column to get end-time. The start-time and end-time columns are in datetime64[ns] type while the duration is [int64] type

```
start-time,duration
2012-01-02 05:57:38,1168
2012-04-02 06:18:39,58
```

I first convert the duration column to hh:mm:ss in timedelta format to allow me to do the addition. The duration column is successfully converted to timedelta but gets displayed as 1970-01-01T00:19:28Z. How can I get rid of the 1970 date part and remain with only hh:mm:ss time part but still as timedelta type.

I have tried the below

```
df['duration'] = df['duration'].astype('float64')
df['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['duration'], unit='s').dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'])
df['end-time'] = df['start-time'] + df['duration']
```

**Output**

```
start-time,end-time,duration
2012-04-02 05:57:38,2012-04-02 06:17:06,1970-01-01T00:19:28Z
2012-04-02 06:18:39,2012-04-02 06:19:37,1970-01-01T00:00:58Z
```

**Desired output**

```
start-time,end-time,duration
2012-01-02 05:57:38,2012-04-02 06:17:06,00:19:28
2012-04-02 06:18:39,2012-04-02 06:19:37,00:00:58
```

Comment: `df['duration'] = df['duration'].dt.time`? or calculate the different between start and end `df['duration'] = df[['start-time', 'end-time']].diff(axis=1)['end-time']`

Comment: I only have the start-time and duration and use that to get the end-time. timedelta also does not have the dt.time attribute I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert from int -> float -> datetime -> timedelta

You can just go from int seconds to timedelta directly

```
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'], unit='s')
df['end-time'] = df['start-time'] + df['duration']
df = df[['start-time','end-time','duration']]
```

**Input**

```
         start-time  duration
2012-01-02 05:57:38      1168
2012-04-02 06:18:39        58
```

**Output**

```
         start-time            end-time        duration
2012-01-02 05:57:38 2012-01-02 06:17:06 0 days 00:19:28
2012-04-02 06:18:39 2012-04-02 06:19:37 0 days 00:00:58
```

Comment: Thanks but I still get the duration as 1970-01-01T00:19:28Z

Comment: Are you doing anything else to the dataframe before or afterwards?

Comment: Yes I do lots of stuff before but not afterwards

Comment: Displaying in that way means that it's likely getting converted to a string somewhere, rather than remaining as a timedelta64[ns] dtype